# ios append button on button press

Tags: ios, uibutton, subclass

Firstly, I am new to ios development and I am trying to understand how to approach this.

This screengrab is from another app. When you press the green plus button it appends more buttons like the one at the top depending on how many times you press the green plus button

[image]

I am trying to replicate this but dont know where to start. My question is, would it be best to create a subclass for the top button? And then somehow append that subclass button each time the green plus button is pressed?

Comment: Consider using `UITableView` for this, and adding a new cell every time the button is pressed.

Comment: I tried using UITableView but couldnt get it to work how I needed it to as when you press either Time or Item on the top button it changes to a UITableView like this http://i.imgur.com/yEVBSsZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to learn this myself, so I created sample project and here is simple tutorial how this can be done. Not perfect but maybe you get the basic idea how this works.

---

Create Table View Controller in Interface Builder. Then add buttons and text fields to prototype cell.

[image: Table view controller and prototype cells]

---

Add new class to your project, let's call it with name MyTableViewController. Set Table View Controller's class to MyTableViewController (in interface builder).

[image]

---

Set identifier for prototype cell. I used `defaultCell` value.

[image]

---

Set tag values for buttons and text fields.

[image]

I used these tag values:

- Plus button: 100
- Time button: 110
- Item button: 120
- Text field 1: 10
- Text field 2: 20
- Text field 3: 30

---

MyTableViewController.h (**note:** UITableView is linked as `tView` variable)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

/* Data array */
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *data;
/* Expanded cell */
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger expandedCell;

/* Table view */
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tView;

@end
```

MyTableViewController.m

```
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@interface MyTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    /* No cells expanded by default */
    _expandedCell = -1;

    /* Create data array */
    _data = [NSMutableArray new];

    /* Add two cells to data array */
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self newDefaultCell:0];
    [_data addObject:cell];
    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self newDefaultCell:1];
    [_data addObject:cell2];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)newDefaultCell:(NSUInteger)index {

    /* Initialize new UITableViewCell using prototype cell */
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"defaultCell"];

    /* Initialize buttons for this cell */
    UIButton *plusButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [plusButton setTag:index];
    [plusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(plusButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *timeButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:110];
    [timeButton setTag:index];
    [timeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(timeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *itemButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
    [itemButton setTag:index];
    [itemButton addTarget:self action:@selector(itemButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /* Returns UITableViewCell object from data array */
    return [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /* If cell is expanded, return row height 140 */
    if(_expandedCell == indexPath.row) {
        return 140;
    } /* else return row height 30 */
    else return 30;
}

- (void)plusButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    /* Create new UITableViewCell */
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [self newDefaultCell:[_data count]];
    /* Add UITableViewCell to data array */
    [_data addObject:newCell];

    /* Update table view */
    [_tView beginUpdates];
    [_tView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([_data count]-1)inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [_tView endUpdates];
}

- (void)timeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    /* Expand this cell to show UITextFields */
    _expandedCell = [button tag];

    /* UITableViewCell from data array, index is button's tag value */
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_data objectAtIndex:[button tag]];

    /* You can access text fields using viewWithTag: call */
    UITextField *tf1 = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    UITextField *tf2 = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:20];
    UITextField *tf3 = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:30];

    /* Reload UITableViewRow */
    NSArray *indexes = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[button tag] inSection:0]];
    [_tView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [_tView beginUpdates];
    [_tView endUpdates];
}

- (void)itemButtonPressed:(id)sender {

}

@end
```

---

And it's done.